# Carbon C Event Handlers for movement of scroll bar of window

Tags: macos, macos-carbon

I am trying to find how can we catch the events of that whenever a scroll bar is moved. Scroll bar can also be moved programmatic-ally so, mouse scroll events wont work here.

I am using Carbon, Mac

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: How did you create the scroll bar?

Comment: Scroll bars are created using Qt. Now I want to use Carbon event handlers to catch the actions on those scroll bars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try kEventControlIndicatorMoved and/or kEventControlValueFieldChanged.